# Check if two points collide with any element in a list

Tags: python, pygame

How to check if two points collide with elements in list

If both points are colliding with any element in a list ,I want to do something ,but how could I check if both collide

```
for i in range(len(finger)):
    if btn1.collidepoint(finger[i]):
        move()
    if btn2.collidepoint(finger[i]):
        move2()
```

I could check them separately but not at same time . I want to do something like

```
#if btn1 and btn2 collides with any element in list:
     #Do something
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and [generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```py
if any(btn1.collidepoint(f) for f in finger) and any(btn2.collidepoint(f) for f in finger):
    # [...]
```

Comment: @Payal What "is not working"? What is the actual behavior and what is the expected behavior? Possibly I've misunderstood your question. However your question is completely unclear. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: No you haven't misunderstood my question , I tried the code but it didn't work ,my if statement didn't executed

Comment: @Payal What do you mean by "didn't executed"? Is there an error?